# How do i remove the items from the searched list once the entire text is removed from the search textBox using JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, livesearch

I have implemented live search using Jquery and JSON. Initially no results are displayed as there is no text in the search box. When I write some text in the search textbox it shows me the results. However the results are shown even when I have removed the text from the search textbox.

How can I remove the results once everything is removed from the textbox?

Following is the jquery code:

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
  var searchField= $('#search').val();
  console.log(searchField);
  var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i" );
  $.getJSON('js/data.json', function(data){
    var output = '<ul class="seachresults">';
    $.each(data, function(key,val){
      if((val.name.search(myExp)!= -1) || (val.company.search(myExp)!= -1)){
      output += '<li>';
      output += '<h2>'+ val.name +'</h2>';
      output += '<img src="images/'+val.shortname+'_tn.png" alt="'+val.name+ '" />'  ;
      output += '<p>'+ val.description +'</p>';
      output += '<h2>'+ val.company +'</h2>';
      output += '<h2>'+ val.price +'</h2>';
      output += '</li>';
    }
    });
    output+= '</ul>';
    $('#update').html(output);
  });

});
```

Following is the HTML code:

```
<div id='searcharea'>
  <label for="search">Product Directory</label>
  <p>Search</p>
  <input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="info" />
</div>
<div id='update'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You check if there is some value entered using `if ($.trim(searchField) != '') {` .. If there is some value, then existing code will work, else it will clear the result container. So you initialize `var output = '';` outside `if` condition.

Updated code below:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var searchField = $(this).val();
  console.log(searchField);
  var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  var output = '';
  if ($.trim(searchField) != '') {
    $.getJSON('js/data.json', function(data) {
      output = '<ul class="seachresults">';
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        if ((val.name.search(myExp) != -1) || (val.company.search(myExp) != -1)) {
          output += '<li>';
          output += '<h2>' + val.name + '</h2>';
          output += '<img src="images/' + val.shortname + '_tn.png" alt="' + val.name + '" />';
          output += '<p>' + val.description + '</p>';
          output += '<h2>' + val.company + '</h2>';
          output += '<h2>' + val.price + '</h2>';
          output += '</li>';
        }
      });
      output += '</ul>';
    });
      $('#update').html(output);
  } else {
      $('#update').html(output);
  }
});
```

Comment: $('#update').html(output) needs to be added in the if loop also. Rest its working fine. Thanks

Comment: `$('#update').html(output);` is outside/after `if` loop. This means, it will always get correct value which is set in `output` variable.

Comment: But with the above code i cant see any results if i type something inside the search box

Comment: when i add `$('#update').html(output);` after `output += '</ul>';`, it works fine